# Unable to extract the value from the first page of all pdf's saved in a folder

Tags: python, text-extraction

i have some 22 pdf files saved in folder . The pdfs are in french and the first page contains one single line of text with a date in the beginning. i am trying to extract the date from each of the first page and put it to a data frame . but when i am running the code its producing more number of rows of date values than 22 .

Here is the code i have written

```
chk_files = os.listdir("C:\\Users")
new_pdf_files = [fil for fil in chk_files if ".pdf" in fil]
for fil in new_pdf_files:
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fil)
    NumPage = object.getNumPages()
    for i in range(0, NumPage):
        pdfFileObj = open(fil, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        s= (pageObj.extractText())
        partitioned_string = s.partition('B')
        partitioned_string[0]
        translator = google_translator()
        translate_text = translator.translate(partitioned_string[0],lang_src='fr', lang_tgt='en')  
        string_date= str(translate_text)
        upper_string_date=string_date.upper()
        dt = parse(upper_string_date)
        announement_date = print(dt.strftime('%d-%B-%Y').upper())
print(announement_date)
```

All the first page have one line of text like this

"24 mai 2021BULLETIN DES ANNONCES LEGALES OBLIGATOIRESBulletin n°622102172Page 1Avis de convocation / avis de réunion'" and i am trying to extract the first date in beginning

Out put

24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021
24-MAY-2021

Its coming 196 times but should be 22

Comment: Add your sample output as well that you are getting, to see and help you out

Comment: @ Ank i have added the output

Comment: why are you running this loop:   `for i in range(0, NumPage):`

Comment: seems like you are getting page 0, NumPage times

Comment: Thanks Ank i got it where i made the mistake